# Invalid Podfile - React Native

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I have a react native project I downloaded from GitHub and my pod file downloaded as an executable - when I went to go do pod install I get this error:

invalid pod file: cannot load such file

any idea on how to fix this? 
why did my podfile upload as an executable on github?

Comment: Can you share your Podfile ?

Comment: did you try running pod init...

Comment: @EL173 I deleted my old pod file and ran pod init. Still got weird errors. My friend and I decided not to use GitHub for react native and are just going to zip the file. We don't know what else to do. Anytime he pushes to GitHub his pod file gets messed up.